# disjointness of sorts of a many sorted algebra

Tags: logic, universal-algebra

Given a many-sroted signature `sig` with the sorts `S1, S2, ..., Sn`.

A many sorted algebra `alg` of signature `sig` comprises a carrier set `Ai` for each sort `Si`, i.e., `A1` is the carrier set of `S1`, etc.

**Questions**

1. Do `A1, A2, ..., An` have to be pairwise-disjoint? I have been reading through many definitions and none explicitly excludes this possiblity. If that is not allowed; what is the reasoning/implications behind that?
2. Is there any reason that prevents a sort `Si` from being a composite sort, e.g., assume `A1` to be natural numbers `N` and `A2` to be the power set of `N` (the set of all sets the can be constructed from the natural numbers `N`).
3. Do you recommend some introductory references?

**EDIT 1**

As an example of question (1), consider that we have two sorts: `NATURALS` and `INTEGERS`, which, in some algebra, have the carrier sets `N` (natural numbers) and `Z` (integral numbers). I think that this is a very natural requirement. For example, assume we are interested in subtraction of natural numbers which then will be expressed as function: `subtract : NATURALS x NATURALS -> INTEGERS`

Comment: 1) [usually yes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-sorted_logic#Example)

Comment: 2) but the power-set of $\mathbb N$ has no natural numbers as elements but set of numbers.

Comment: 1) any intuition behind that restriction?

Comment: 2) it was just an example of a composite carrier set.

Comment: Yes, different "categories" of objects like animal species: a cat is not a dog.

Comment: How about LandAnimal and WaterAnimal? Isn't a crocodile a member of both?